# when do we need package to call its function or procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, package

Why to create a function or procedure inside a package instead of storing that function or procedure and calling it whenever we need it?

suppose a procedure is created inside a package  to display customer name the the customer id that we are passing to the procedure.

But if we do not create the procedure inside the package, how much difference in the both scenarios?

Do we need to create package just to define one procedure?

Comment: Could you add more tags to your question, at least what programming language you're talking about? Also a quick example would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

A Package allows some grouping of related procedures, hiding "internal" procedures, maintaining package global state and specifying an interface some else can program against.

If you don't need any of this a stand-alone procedure will do just fine